# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when fetching from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, express

When I run the code for the following snippet, it gives me the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. I'm new to coding so I would really love some help. Thank you.

```
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/add-user', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'User 1'
      })
    }).then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => alert(data))
    .catch(error => alert(error))
```

I expected it to show the parsed output but it only gives me the error.

Comment: Your `res` maybe not in JSON format, use `return res.text()` to check the error returned by the fetch request.

Comment: enclose User 1 in double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 try {
await fetch('http://localhost:3000/add-user', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }),
 body: {
    name: 'User 1'
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
   
  });
```

} catch (error) {}